# Solving the ODE: $ y'(t)=y^2(t) - 5sin(t) - 25cos^2(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to analytically solve  $$y'(t)=y^2(t)-5\sin(t)-25\cos^2(t)$$
Is the equation convergent? (for using numerical methods)

Comment: Plz mention the method you use with description

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Bernoulli,separable and complete didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

There is of course a particular periodic solution $y_p(t)=5\cos(t)$.  Then letting $y=y_p+z$ we have a Bernoulli equation
$$
z'(t)=10\cos(t)z(t)+z(t)^2
$$
So letting $v=1/z$ we have
$$
v'(t)+10\cos(t)v(t)=-1
$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, with $a_0=y(0)$, then we can compute the coefficients $a_n$, $n\geq1$. For example:
$$a_1=y'(0)=y(0)^2-5\sin(0)-25\cos^2(0)=a_0-25,$$
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Riccati Differential Equation, as it can be re-written as $y'(t) = y^2(t) - 5(\sin t - 5 \cos^2 t)$. It doesn't seem that it can be solved analytically, neither that a closed form solution exists.

A sample solution family can be seen here (means numerical solutions yielding by taken different sample values for an initial $y(0)$ let's say) :

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$[image]

Finally, convergence regarding a numerical method is dependent on the approach and method you use.